# функции шаблоны. Подсчитать среднее арифм. ненулевых элементов,расположенных над побочной диагональю. с++ проблема: среднее арифм. считается неверно

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

template <typename X>
void enterArray(X**a,int n)
{cout<<"Vvedite massiv"<<n<<"*"<<n<<endl;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
        cin>> a[i][j];}

template <typename X>
void print(X**a,int n)
{
       for (int i=0; i<n; i++, cout<<endl)
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
 cout<<setw(6)<<a[i][j]<< " ";
}

int main()
{int n;
cin>>n;
int s=0;
    int ** a = new int * [n];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        a[i]=new int [n];
    enterArray(a,n);
    print(a,n);}
    {for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=n-1;j>0;j--)
        {
            if(a[i][j]!=0) { s+=a[i][j]; n++;}
        }

    cout<<"Sred. arif="<<s/n;}
    return 0;}
```

Comment: Вы знаете, что написали неправильно или что?.. Вопрос в чем состоит?

Comment: Я не понимаю почему моя программа только выводит массив и всё. подсчета не происходит

Comment: Скобочки надо аккуратно расставлять, в `main` `return 0` стоит внутри цикла, соответственно он заканчивается на первой же итерации.

Comment: Это исправила) выводит массив теперь и после запрашивает число.

Comment: потому что в остальной части программы вы ожидаете ввода для вторичной инициализации массива .

Comment: А  если вот такой вариант?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

после вызова функции `print(a,n)`; т.е после вывода полученного массива вам нужно  переходить к решению главной части задачи, а именно, посчитать среднее арифметическое, расположенных над побочной диагональю.

```
int k = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
    for(int j = n - i - 2; j >= 0; --j)
        if (a[i][j]) {
            ++k;        // считаем количество ненулевых элементов
            s += a[i][j]; // их сумма
        }
cout << (double)s / k;  // среднее арефметическое
```

Comment: Всё, теперь разобралась) Огромное спасибо)